# CSS style specific to browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, webkit, margin

I have a CSS class as follows

```
.sub-title
{
    -webkit-margin-before : 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start : 10px;
    margin: 10px 8px 2px 20px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

With the above class I want to apply margin for a div.
In IE browser i want to apply "margin: 10px 8px 2px 20px;"  and in chrome i want to apply margin as "-webkit-margin-before : 1em;
                   -webkit-margin-start : 10px;".

But even in chrome, it is considering "margin: 10px 8px 2px 20px;" only, instead of webkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

place the `margin: 10px 8px 2px 20px;` before `-webkit-margin-before : 1em;`

css always takes the last style applied to an element. In that case first it will apply the`margin: 10px 8px 2px 20px;` and then the `-webkit-margin-before : 1em;` . in case of IE the second line will be ignored.

```
.sub-title
{
    margin: 10px 8px 2px 20px;
    -webkit-margin-before : 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start : 10px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```